# Switching from "if" to "elseif" breaks code

Tags: php

I'm using multiple if statements to check a containing div, and output an image based on the container name. The code was working fine until I add a final "else" or change the if's out to elseif and I can't figure out why that's happening. When I try to add the else or elseif, the entire page fails to load. Any idea why this is happening?

```
            <?php
            if($viewMore['container_type'] == 'Large IMG' || $viewMore['container_type'] == 'Gallery') {
                $photoSql = "SELECT * FROM  `cms_uploads` WHERE  (`tableName`='site_content' AND `recordNum` = '".$viewMore['num']."' AND `fieldname`= 'large_images') ORDER BY `order`";
                $photoResult = $database->query($photoSql);
                $photoResultNum = $database->num_rows($photoResult);

                $photoArray = array();
                while($photoResultRow = $database->fetch_array($photoResult)) {
                    array_push($photoArray, $photoResultRow);
                }

                $large = 0; foreach ($photoArray as $photo => $upload): if (++$large == 2) break;
            ?>

                <img class="features" src="<?php echo $upload['urlPath'] ?>">

            <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php
            elseif($viewMore['container_type'] == 'Medium IMG') {
                $photoSql = "SELECT * FROM  `cms_uploads` WHERE  (`tableName`='site_content' AND `recordNum` = '".$viewMore['num']."' AND `fieldname`= 'small_images') ORDER BY `order`";
                $photoResult = $database->query($photoSql);
                $photoResultNum = $database->num_rows($photoResult);

                $photoArray = array();
                while($photoResultRow = $database->fetch_array($photoResult)) {
                    array_push($photoArray, $photoResultRow);
                }

                $medium = 0; foreach ($photoArray as $photo => $upload): if (++$medium == 2) break;
            ?>

                <img class="features" src="<?php echo $upload['urlPath'] ?>">

            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php } ?>

                      <?php else { ?> SOMETHING HERE <?php } ?>
```

EDIT:

Other notes

I've tried wrapping the break; in brackets because I thought that piece following the count might be messing with something. Also removing the counter altogether or adding a semi colon after the endforeach didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried another solution besides using break statements?  I get very weary whenever I see break statements in anything besides a select-case block.

Comment: Dev's answer below is correct. I would suggest that clean and consistent formatting of your code (especially indenting blocks) would help you find these problems more quickly. There is rarely any good reason, for example, to have multiple statements on a single line.

Comment: Also you should understand how the [alternative control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) are meant to work before using them. IMO they're really best left to building templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you close your PHP block, think about all the text/HTML outside it being put into PHP's echo function.

What gave me alarm bells was this part:

```
<?php } ?>

    <?php else { ?> ...
```

What that translates into is:

```
if (...) {

} echo "[whitespace]"; else {

}
```

which clearly makes your else block unexpected.

You should not close the PHP block between your closing if and opening else, i.e. do this instead:

```
...
} else { 
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize white space was being added in there